# How can I compare orthogonal contrasts using emmeans for lme4 model?

Tags: r, model, lme4, mixed, emmeans

I have an lme4 mixed model with multiple variables. I am interested in the orthogonal contrast for one of the variables in the model which has three groups (say A, B, C). I want the compare A to the average of B and C. How can I do this using emmeans in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach that I imagine would work:

```
mtcars$cyl <-as.factor(mtcars$cyl)

fit <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl, mtcars)

library(emmeans)
fit

emm_fit <- emmeans(fit, specs = "cyl")

contrast(emm_fit, list(cyl = c(1, -.5, -.5)))
```

This is the equivalent of x_1 - .5x_2-.5x_3

This results in the following:

```
contrast estimate   SE df t.ratio p.value
 cyl          5.16 1.37 28 3.781   0.0008
```

This fits a model, uses emmeans to develop the marginals, then in the `contrast` function we look at the difference between 4 cylinders from the average of 6 and 8. For more details see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/comparisons.html#contrasts